# How to run a TestNG.xml through a Shell Script in Jenkins?

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, jenkins, testng

**First Step**: I created a BAT File with below mentioned commands and tried running it > It did successfully run the TestNG Suite with all the tests I had configured.

**Next Step**: was to set up the Jenkins I was trying to run the bat file with the Add build setup > execute Windows bat command >

```
cd /d %~dp0

set classpath=bin;lib\*;lib\selenium\*;lib\POI\*;bin\com\healthcare\*;bin\com\healthcare\reports\*;

java org.testng.TestNG Smoke_OrderIDCards.xml
```

And also

`run smoke.bat` which has all the above commands

And also with

```
call %WORKSPACE%\smoke.bat
```

and also

```
run %WORKSPACE%\smoke.bat
```

it kept throwing the error in Jenkins console as:

```
[Purchaser] $ cmd /c call /proj/jenkins/tmp/jenkins9142107435735320094.bat
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "/proj/jenkins/workspace/Purchaser"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:850)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

But I figured what if the server it's running on, is not Windows and tried running a sample command through `Add Build Step > Execute Shell`

with the command as `echo $WORKSPACE` and that was a success. And I tried looking up everywhere I could to finout how to do the same through shell script and was not able to.

Now I need to know how to run the same commands I mentioned above `(set classpath and run the TestNG.xml file)` through shell commands. Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: What kind of shell script do you need?  There's dozens of them out there.

Comment: Any simple one which helps me execute the similar commands as the ones I am trying to run through Windows Batch Command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd $WORKSPACE

java -cp "lib/*:lib/selenium/*:lib/POI/*:bin:" org.testng.TestNG $WORKSPACE/Smoke_OrderIDCards.xml
```

I referred to the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) for setting classpath syntax as above.

This is the command I have given in the Execute Shell Command field for the Jenkins Configuration and it did work!

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `%WORKSPACE%\my_test.bat` results in C:\Tools\Jenkins\workspace\my_test\my_test.bat, in my case and the file is not found. My file is in a folder called, c:\src\bat.

This works for me:

```
c:\src\bat\my_test.bat
```

This is how I have set it up in Jenkins:

[image]